# DAX: How can I check if a value in column A has 2 different values in column B?

Tags: dax

So first let me input some example data, which would look like this:

```
|  title  |  item  |
--------------------
| title 1 | item A |
| title 2 | item A |
| title 3 | item C |
| title 3 | item B |
| title 1 | item E |
| title 2 | item F |
```

So i'm aiming to extract the items that are not common (items that are not included in multiple titles at the same time). For example :

```
|  title  |  item  |  result  |
-------------------------------
| title 1 | item A |   False  |
| title 2 | item A |   False  |
| title 3 | item C |   True   |
| title 3 | item B |   True   |
| title 1 | item E |   True   |
| title 2 | item F |   True   |
```

Can it be achieved using DAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new column (calculated column) with the following DAX:

```
result =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( myTable[title] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( myTable, myTable[item] )
) = 1
```

The `ALLEXCEPT ( myTable, myTable[item] )`part will filter the table, keeping the rows with the same [item] value as the current row. It does this by removing all filters from the row-context, except the filter on the [item] column.

The DISTINCTCOUNT will then count the distinct values in the [title] column of the filtered table.

When the outcome equals 1, the result will be 'True', if not the result will be 'False'

[image]